# Bash Obtener valores e imprimir en pantalla

Tags: bash

Tengo un archivo llamado data.csv que contiene los siguientes valores:

Nombre,Apellido,numero_telefono,mail

Lo que quiesiera hacer es que en un script, luego de ejecutarlo me ejecute ciertas acciones x por cada linea?
Ejemplo de data.csv

```
Pepe,Night,6778789789,pepe@google.com,carcel
Ramon,Silver,091827331,ramon@google.com,casa
Julian,Weich,786789182,Julian@google.com,departamento
Julian,Weich,786789182,Julian@google.com,calle
```

Se como obtener cada valor:

```
nombre=`cut -d , -f 1 data.csv`
apellido=`cut -d , -f 2 data.csv`
tel=`cut -d , -f 3 data.csv`
mail=`cut -d , -f 4 data.csv`
lugar=`cut -d , -f 5 data.csv`
```

Ahora como puedo hacer para que con cada valor ejecutee una accion diferente? Necesitaria armar algo que lea linea por linea

Comment: jajajaja "cárcel" mandó Què querès decir exactamente con "con cada valor ejecute una acción diferente"? Te referís a cada fila? O a cada campo de la fila?

Comment: cada fila, dependiendo el lugar donde vive

Comment: Y cuál es el criterio de `lugar` y qué habría que hacer?

Comment: dependiendo el lugar,  se debe ejecutar un comando cualquiera ls un echo, etc-

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
# guardar separador actual
oldifs=$IFS
while IFS=, read -r nombre apellido tel mail lugar
do
    # con un if podes filtrar y realizar lo que necesites dependiendo del lugar
    if [[ "$lugar" == "departamento" ]]; then
        echo "$lugar"
    fi
done < data.csv
# restaurar el separador
IFS=$oldifs
```

Comment: voy a probar y te cuento